# Blender 2.8 refuses to run on my PC

Tags: opengl

When I try to run Blender 2.8, I get the error "Device init failed: 0x80070490"

My Windows 10 PC has the following graphics card:

**NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960**

According to the geforce.com site, the OpenGL version on this card is 4.4, which should be plenty for Blender 2.8. So why is it refusing to run?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You are most possibly using the Installer version of Blender 2.80 Beta. Try the zipped version, extract it to your desktop and run blender.exe from there.

Comment: No, I used the zipped version.

Comment: It should work. It is very likely that updating your GPU drivers will help, but if it doesn't, you should report this as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your driver. Sometimes older versions don't have the same support as newer ones.